# Booting an emulator with modified/custom userdata.img file

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been trying to boot an emulator with user data from a real device. When we create an Android emulator, by default it uses the userdata.img file from AVD location. In my case, C:\Users\User.Android\avd\emulator.avd\userdata.img

I want to load my userdata such as pictures, music from my real phone into an emulator. I created a dd image of **data partition**(I named it userdata.img) from a real device and replaced the original userdata.img file from my emulator.avd location. I also made sure that there is enough disk space while creating this emulator(The size of the image taken from real device is 800MB and DISK SIZE given to emulator is 1000MB).

When I launch the emulator with these modifications, it is not loading with newly added image(It keeps loading for hours and hours but not reaching the home screen). Please guide what are the other steps I need to consider to load it.

Real device is SONY C1505 model running JellyBean(Android 4.1.1). Emulator is also created using JellyBean(Android 4.1).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the data partition doesn't have enough space - try running the emulator yourself with the option

```
-partition-size 1024
```

You could also use

```
-show-kernel
```

to see kernel logs to identify the problem